# Exp:resso Store - Paypal Pro hosted?

Tags: expresso-store, paypal

I am using the fantastic Exp:resso Store. My client has an account with PayPal Pro. Their host hasn't got the option for SSL certs.

I'm just wondering if PayPal Pro can still be used on site? Or if I use the module can I divert it to the hosted version at PayPal?

Sorry for the simple question. Normally I would just try, but I have a meeting with the client and would like to know the answer before then.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

PayPal Pro is an on-site gateway therefore you must have an SSL certificate setup and installed on your site for the data to be transferred properly and for you to be PCI compliant. You can use the PayPal Express Gateway which is an off-site gateway.

Personally I think it is crazy that the host doesn't offer an SSL option and would recommend that you consider moving to a more modern host.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is crazy too. They won't move - crazy. Hanks for the reply Justin. Have you PayPal Pro Hosted? Apparently they offer it along side the onsite Pro version.

Comment: I have not used Pro Hosted (or even heard about it) I despise PayPal with every bit of my soul. If you are not wanting to on-site host it then I don't see the reason to not use just a standard PayPal account which allows both PayPal checkout and Guest checkout via credit cards. There are no monthly fees that way.

Comment: To be honest this is the first time I've even heard of PayPal Pro Hosted. There doesn't really seem to be any advantage over PayPal Express. As Justin pointed out though, you should really just remind your client who is being paid as the web expert, and tell them to move to a host which supports SSL.

Comment: I know I know. They are, lets say, 'challenging' customers! I've been reading the docs:

Comment: Sorry - Timed out: I know I know. They are, lets say, 'challenging' customers! I've been reading the docs. You can basically just send PayPal a form with cart details so it seems quite easy to code. However, I have said I won't code it so it sends address details etc. So the customer will have to fill in two lots of data I am presuming. I'm also not sure if Store will accept return URL and progress the order. The client wants the terminal feature that Pro offers. They are an adult orientated site so many providers aren't interested. The hosted version is basically an offsite option.

Comment: Docs are here if anyone is interested: https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/hostedsolution_uk.pdf. Page 15. Thanks again for the comments guys.

Comment: I would be careful trusting PayPal for an adult oriented site as even under normal circumstances they are notorious for suspending accounts for charge backs (also I am pretty sure it is against their terms of service). There are a few merchants accounts that are specifically there for adult oriented sites that I would recommend you investigate before deciding on PayPal. CCBill is pretty much the standard for adult websites these days but Payza is very similar to PayPal in terms of functionality and is also adult friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal seems to have brought up a new way of integrating paypal pro see link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/

Is this version supported by expresso store and if not are there any plans for future support?
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/ppp-direct-payment/